How can I use dict in response_schemas using Gemini API?
I'm attempting to enforce a schema on a prompt response from Gemini. As made clear is supported in the 'structured output' docs.
For important implementation reasons, my schema contains dictionaries as a crucial part of it's structure.
However, they seem to be causing issues with Gemini.
I end up with: ValueError: Unknown field for Schema: additionalProperties if a dict is present anywhere in the Schema.
My schema is here:
leagues.py (module)
from typing_extensions import TypedDict

class LeagueStandings(TypedDict):
  teams: dict[str, int]

class LeaguesSchema(TypedDict):
  leagues: dict[str, LeagueStandings]

My executor is here:
gemini_executor.py (module)
from leagues.leagues import LeaguesSchema
import google.generativeai

class GeminiExecutor():

    def __init__(self):
        GEMINI_API_KEY = "********"
        google.generativeai.configure(api_key=GEMINI_API_KEY)

    async def initialise(self, system_prompt: str) -> None:
        self._gemini_model = google.generativeai.GenerativeModel(
            model_name="gemini-1.5-flash-8b",
            system_instruction=system_prompt
        )
        self._generation_config = google.generativeai.GenerationConfig(
            response_mime_type="application/json", response_schema=LeaguesSchema, 
        )
    
    async def execute(self, task_prompt: str) -> str:
        result = await self._gemini_model.generate_content_async(
            task_prompt, generation_config=self._generation_config
        )
        return result.text


My entrypoint is here:
main.py
    from gemini_executor.gemini_executor import GeminiExecutor
    
    executor = GeminiExecutor()
    await executor.initialise("You know lots about football.")
    response = await executor.execute("Respond with data about various football leagues from around the world last season, and the points totals of the teams within them. 6 leagues will do.")
    print(response.text)

But when I run this, I get the error:
from:  .venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/proto/message.py:724

ignore_unknown_fields = False                                                                            
key = 'additionalProperties'
kwargs = {}│                                                                                   mapping = {'additionalProperties': {'$ref': '#/$defs/LeaguesSchema'}, 'type_': <Type.OBJECT: 6>}                                                                                   
marshal = <proto.marshal.marshal.Marshal object at 0x105b34340>  
params = {}
pb_type = None                                                                             
self = <repr-error 'Unknown field for Schema: _pb'>
value = {'$ref': '#/$defs/LeaguesSchema'}

                                      
ValueError: Unknown field for Schema: additionalProperties


This error is thrown after the self._gemini_model.generate_content_async call.
I'm pretty sure it's the incoming response that's the culprit, but It appears to a problem with marshalling some data into the dictionary parts of the schema, which sprout this "additionalProperties" key. However the docs state that Gemini supports exactly this.
I have tried removing these dict objects and replacing them with literally anything else. Gemini obviously struggles to fit the data into an unsuitable schema, but most importantly it doesn't give me an error.
However, I'd like to be able to enforce my schema on the response data.
I have also tried replacing this built-in dict in the Schema, with Dict imported from the typing module. Same issue.
